# Trying to create a wordpress plugin that generates a blog based on a form using OpenAI API

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api, openai-api

As the title says, I am trying to write a WordPress plugin that extracts info from a Contact 7 Form, sends it to the OpenAI API, and returns the generated text in a text box for the user to read. I have never created a WordPress plugin, so I was unsure what to do. With some guidance, I managed to reach this:

The problem is that when I click the generate button, nothing shows up, looking at inspect element shows that i just get "text: null" returned from the api request, does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

**openai-blog-generator.php**

```
/*
Plugin Name: AI Blog Generator
Description: Generates blog posts using OpenAI's GPT-3 model
Version: 1.0
Author: trobanko
*/

// Define constants for OpenAI API
define('OPENAI_API_KEY', 'your_openai_api_key');
define('OPENAI_API_URL', 'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines');

// Add shortcode for Contact Form 7 form
add_shortcode('ai_blog_generator_form', 'ai_blog_generator_form_shortcode');
function ai_blog_generator_form_shortcode() {
  error_log("1");
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div class="ai-blog-generator-form">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="10" title="Contact form 1"]'); ?>
  </div>
  <?php
  return ob_get_clean();
}

// Add custom endpoint for generating blog post
add_action('rest_api_init', 'ai_blog_generator_register_endpoint');
function ai_blog_generator_register_endpoint() {
  error_log("2");
  register_rest_route('ai-blog-generator/v1', '/generate-blog', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'ai_blog_generator_generate_blog',
  ));
}

// Callback function for generating blog post
function ai_blog_generator_generate_blog($request) {
  error_log("3");
  $params = $request->get_params();

  // Get input data from form fields
  $topic = sanitize_text_field($params['blog_topic']);
  $style = sanitize_text_field($params['writing_style']);
  $outline = sanitize_textarea_field($params['outline']);

  error_log("Input Data: Topic: " . $topic . ", Writing Style: " . $style . ", Outline: " . $outline);

  // Define prompt for OpenAI API
  $prompt = "Blog topic: $topic\nWriting style: $style\nOutline: $outline\nGenerate blog post:";
  error_log("Prompt: " . $prompt);

  // Set up API request
  $data = array(
    'prompt' => $prompt,
    'temperature' => 0.5,
    'max_tokens' => 500,
    'n' => 1,
  );
  $args = array(
    'headers' => array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . OPENAI_API_KEY,
    ),
    'body' => json_encode($data),
    'timeout' => 30,
  );

  // Send request to OpenAI API
  error_log("Sending request to OpenAI API...");
  $response = wp_remote_post(OPENAI_API_URL . '/davinci-003/completions', $args);
  error_log("Received response from OpenAI API");

  // Parse response
  if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    error_log("API Error: " . $error_message);
    return new WP_Error('api_error', $error_message, array('status' => 500));
  } else {
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $json = json_decode($body, true);
    $text = $json['choices'][0]['text'];
    error_log("Generated text: " . $text);
    return array('text' => $text);
  }
}



// Add script for generating blog post
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ai_blog_generator_enqueue_scripts');
function ai_blog_generator_enqueue_scripts() {
  error_log("4");
  wp_enqueue_script('ai-blog-generator', plugins_url('/js/ai-blog-generator.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
  wp_localize_script('ai-blog-generator', 'aiBlogGeneratorSettings', array(
    'apiUrl' => esc_url_raw(rest_url('ai-blog-generator/v1/generate-blog')),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
  ));
}

// Add CSS for Contact Form 7 form
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ai_blog_generator_enqueue_styles');
function ai_blog_generator_enqueue_styles() {
  error_log("5");
  wp_enqueue_style('ai-blog-generator', plugins_url('/css/ai-blog-generator.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.0', 'all');
}

// Add settings link to plugin page
add_filter('plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'ai_blog_generator_settings_link');
function ai_blog_generator_settings_link($links) {
  $settings_link = '<a href="admin.php?page=ai-blog-generator-settings">Settings</a>';
  array_push($links, $settings_link);
  return $links;
}

// Register settings page
add_action('admin_menu', 'ai_blog_generator_settings_page');
function ai_blog_generator_settings_page() {
  add_menu_page('AI Blog Generator Settings', 'AI Blog Generator', 'manage_options', 'ai-blog-generator-settings', 'ai_blog_generator_settings');
}

// Display settings page
function ai_blog_generator_settings() {
  ?>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>AI Blog Generator Settings</h1>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
      <?php
      settings_fields('ai_blog_generator_options');
      do_settings_sections('ai_blog_generator_options');
      submit_button();
      ?>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}

// Register settings
add_action('admin_init', 'ai_blog_generator_register_settings');
function ai_blog_generator_register_settings() {
  register_setting('ai_blog_generator_options', 'ai_blog_generator_api_key');
  add_settings_section('ai_blog_generator_api_settings', 'OpenAI API Settings', 'ai_blog_generator_api_settings_callback', 'ai_blog_generator_options');
  add_settings_field('ai_blog_generator_api_key', 'API Key', 'ai_blog_generator_api_key_callback', 'ai_blog_generator_options', 'ai_blog_generator_api_settings');
}

// Display API settings section
function ai_blog_generator_api_settings_callback() {
  echo '<p>Enter your OpenAI API key below:</p>';
}

// Display API key field
function ai_blog_generator_api_key_callback() {
  $api_key = get_option('ai_blog_generator_api_key');
  echo '<input type="text" name="ai_blog_generator_api_key" value="' . esc_attr($api_key) . '" />';
}

// Add API key to API requests
add_filter('http_request_args', 'ai_blog_generator_add_api_key', 10, 2);
function ai_blog_generator_add_api_key($args, $url) {
  if (strpos($url, 'api.openai.com') !== false) {
    $api_key = get_option('ai_blog_generator_api_key');
    if ($api_key) {
      $args['headers']['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $api_key;
    }
  }
  return $args;
}
```

**ai-blog-generator.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#generate-blog').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Form submitted');

    // Get form data
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log('Form data:', formData);

    // Send AJAX request
    $.ajax({
      url: ai_blog_generator_params.endpoint,
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', ai_blog_generator_params.nonce);
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('API response:', response);
        var text = response.text;
        if (text) {
          console.log('Generated text:', text);
          $('#blog-post').html(text);
        } else {
          console.log('Error: Empty response');
          $('#blog-post').html('Error: Empty response');
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('AJAX error:', jqXHR.responseText);
        $('#blog-post').html('Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**ai-blog-generator-rest-api.php**

```
/**
 * Register REST API endpoint for generating blog posts.
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
if (! defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

class AI_Blog_Generator_REST_API {
    /**
     * Initialize REST API endpoint for generating blog posts.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'register_routes'));
    }

    /**
     * Register REST API endpoint for generating blog posts.
     */
    public function register_routes() {
        register_rest_route(
            'ai-blog-generator/v1',
            '/generate-blog',
            array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => array($this, 'generate_blog'),
                'permission_callback' => array($this, 'permission_callback')
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check if user has permissions to access the endpoint.
     */
    public function permission_callback() {
        // Add log message
        error_log('Permission check for AI Blog Generator REST API.');

        return current_user_can('manage_options');
    }

    /**
     * Generate blog post using OpenAI's GPT-3 model.
     */
    public function generate_blog($request) {
        // Add log message
        error_log('Generate blog endpoint called for AI Blog Generator REST API.');

        $params = $request->get_params();

        // Get input data from form fields.
        $topic = sanitize_text_field($params['blog_topic']);
        $style = sanitize_text_field($params['writing_style']);
        $outline = sanitize_textarea_field($params['outline']);

        // Define prompt for OpenAI API.
        $prompt = "Blog topic: $topic\nWriting style: $style\nOutline: $outline\nGenerate blog post:";

        // Set up API request.
        $data = array(
            'prompt' => $prompt,
            'temperature' => 0.5,
            'max_tokens' => 500,
            'n' => 1,
        );
        $args = array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . OPENAI_API_KEY,
            ),
            'body' => json_encode($data),
            'timeout' => 30,
        );

        // Send request to OpenAI API.
        $response = wp_remote_post(OPENAI_API_URL . '/davinci-003/completions', $args);

        // Parse response.
        if (is_wp_error($response)) {
            $error_message = $response->get_error_message();

            // Add log message
            error_log('Error occurred in AI Blog Generator REST API: ' . $error_message);

            return new WP_Error('api_error', $error_message, array('status' => 500));
        } else {
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
            $json = json_decode($body, true);
            $text = $json['choices'][0]['text'];

            // Add log message
            error_log('AI Blog Generator REST API: Generated text: ' . $text);

            return array('text' => $text);
        }
    }
}

new AI_Blog_Generator_REST_API();
```

Comment: I've been fooling around with [something similar](https://github.com/OllieJones/tell-me-more). I did the OpenAI access from php code in the plugin rather than Javascript. This may help you (or not).

Comment: Does your plugin actually work? Because I don't seem to be able to activate it

Comment: @O.Jones seems to be missing the "autoload.php" file required